# How does reconstruction function relate to watershed segmentation?

Tags: image-processing, watershed

I'm trying to understand how watershed work by reading

> The Morphological Approach to Segmentation: The Watershed
>   Transformation S. Beucher and F. Meyer

This document mention reconstruction function. But I don't understand how reconstruction function relate to watershed algorithm ???

Comment: This question might be more suitable for https://dsp.stackexchange.com/ .

Comment: oke, I will post same question in this forum, thank for your advice.